# Value is the same as Text in ListItem

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have this code

```
ListItem item=new ListItem();
item.Text="foo";
item.Value="1"; 
ListItem item2=new ListItem();
item2.Text="bar";
item2.Value="2";
List<ListItem> foobar=new List<ListItem>();
foobar.Add(item); foobar.Add(item2);
foreach(ListItem i in foobar)
{
  lblPrintInfo.Text+="Text:"+i.Text+" Value: "+i.Value;
}
```

And I expect to get `Text:foo Value:1 Text:bar Value:2` like result, but actually I get `Text:foo Value:foo Text:bar Value:bar`. Where am I wrong?

Comment: That code should print `Text:foo Value:1 Text:bar Value:1`.

Comment: Have you tried `"Value:" + i.Value.ToString()`?  Seems like it might need it.

Comment: But Value is string, I don't see thee need of it.

Comment: I guess the error would be somewhere else. Perhaps, how do you bind your ListItems to your control?

Comment: I have ListBox control
`listB.DataSource=foobar; 
 listB.DataBind();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is set the `DataValueField` and `DataTextField` attributes:
Add those lines before the `listB.DataBind();` call:

```
listB.DataTextField = "Text";
listB.DataValueField = "Value";
```

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach(ListItem i in foobar)
{
    lbl.PrintInfo+="Text:"+i.Text+" Value: "+item.Value;
}
```

should be:

```
foreach(ListItem i in foobar)
{
    lbl.PrintInfo+="Text:"+i.Text+" Value: "+i.Value;
}
```

(`i` instead of `item`)

Comment: True but does not explain why he gets no numbers in the output.

Comment: @Francis P, i write directly here I do not copy code form visual studio, what I have is the edited.